# How to get m2m field in validated_data?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, view, django-views

I've a model:

```
class ListingPrice(Timestamps):    
    price = models.ForeignKey("Price", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.ForeignKey("location", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["price", "location"]

class Price(Timestamps):

    package = models.ForeignKey("products.Package", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    locations = models.ManyToManyField("location", through="ListingPrice")
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=3)
```

with a serializer:

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = LocalizedField()

    class Meta:
        model = location
        fields = ['id', 'name']

class PriceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    locations = LocationSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

        class Meta:
            model = Price
        fields = ['package', 'locations', 'price']
        def create(self, validated_data):
             print("validated_data, validated_data)
```

and viewset:

```
class PriceViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Price.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PriceSerializer
    ordering = ['id']
    permissions = {
        "GET": ["view_minimum_listing_price", ],
        "POST": ["add_minimum_listing_price", ],
        'PUT': ['update_minimum_listing_price', ],
        'DELETE': ['delete_minimum_listing_price', ],
    }
```

In testing I'mm using the following:

```
data = {
            "price": 12,
            "package": self.package.id,
            "is_enabled": False,
            "location": self.location
        }

response = self.client.post(path=self.url, data=data, format='json')
```

locations doesn't appear in validated_data?
How to get it to assign locations to the instance with post requests?
I also tried to send it with as ids list, but non works. I only field price, package, is_enabled in validated}_data, but location doesn't appear!

Answer (score 0):

`read_only=True` means the field will be neglected in request body and will only appear in response body

```
locations = LocationSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```

so, remove it and you can access `locations` in `validated_data`

Comment: thanks. for the same use case put method came with an error. `string='Method "PUT" not allowed.` Any ideas?

Comment: @ehathout that's out of scope of the question, but I suspect you don't have `update` method in your viewset, or you misspelled an endpoint

Comment: it comes as empty  [OrderedDict()]. However i passed it as "districts": [
                {'name': self.location.name, 'id': self.location.id},
                ],

Comment: @ehathout you are passing `locations` as `districts`? change the parameter name bro, the name should be the same as declared in serializer